# JFace Dialog disposes widgets when still in use

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a class that extends `jface.dialogs.Dialog`. In that dialog is a save button. When the user pressed that button I need to read the values from some `swt.widgets.Text` fields, but the text fields are disposed already.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MyNewDialog extends Dialog {
private Text txt;

public MyNewDialog(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
}

@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    txt = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    txt.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1));

    return container
}

@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    Button saveButton = createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, "Save", true);
    saveButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent p_e) {
            String string = txt.getText() //widget is disposed exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `IDialogConstants.OK_ID` for your button, you can use the `okPressed()` method. No need to add a specific listener.

```
@Override
protected void okPressed()
{
    value = txt.getText();

    super.okPressed();
}
```

Then create a getter method method to return the `value` variable:

```
public String getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that helped! Is there something similar when I am in a Composite class or do I need to add listeners in that one?

Comment: That's specific to the `Dialog` class. If you're using a `Composite` (not within a dialog) you'll need to add `Listener`s to your buttons.